# iterating over array of objects using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I Know I am missing out on something which I am not able to figure out. Need your help guys.
Basically I want to create multiple thumbnails, for which, the data I am storing in a variable and then trying ng repeat to get the details, but no success. Please help. Here is the plunker for the same. Without directive, using ng-include, its working fine, but with directive, nothing is getting displayed.

directive code:-

```
app.directive('thumbnail', function() {
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'UI/templates/thumbnail.html',
      scope: {
      }
    }
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/q9dWaLpYFusgwGhZDCYF?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.directive('thumbnail', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'UI/templates/thumbnail.html',
  }
});
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks, Can u plz take another moment to kindly explain me how did removing scope part worked? in any case my scope did not store anything

Comment: The problem is, i want to set the id to the thumbnail tag so i can change the values based on the id. Can u plz show me the way?

Comment: Place id property in your data. Otherwise use **track by $index** in ng-repeat. Check updated Plunkr

Comment: No @Arun Shinde, what I mean is, like I have created only one variable in my controller currently($scope.thumbnailDetails), what I want to do is, I want to use the same directive at multiple places, and at each place, i will take the id of the thumbnail and change $scope.thumbnailDetails based on the value of the id, not after the data has been fetched into the variable. Do u get what I want to do?

Comment: by the way, we both r from Pune :D

Comment: Sorry to answer it late. Created Plunker which might help you. I know this is not best but you can follow this way. And good to know that you from Pune too. https://plnkr.co/edit/9ghvDfBSFinzCaBgw3dS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('thumbnail', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: 'UI/templates/thumbnail.html',
  }
});
```

removing isolated scope, will make the data defined in controller available in directive. if you still want to use isolated scope pass the data using = operator

Answer (score 0):

Updated plunker withe the working with directive.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/Yr8DsPb3kt5Jz3CNFGnM?p=preview][1]
```